# Font size NOT changing through .vimrc but can inside vim

Tags: vim

I can change the font size with `set guifont=FixedsysTTF Monospace:h13` inside Vim and works perfectly.

However when I put this inside `~/.vimrc` it stays the same font size no matter what size I set it to, and it's really small.

Here is the screenshot of the problem:

[image: Here is the screenshot of the problem]

Comment: `:verbose set guifont?`

Comment: @phd that outputs: `guifont=FixedsysTTF` \newline `Last set from ~/.vimrc line 27`

Comment: Have you tried alternative syntax: set guifont=FixedsysTTF\ Monospace\ 13 ? Might depend on the gui available: https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Change_font

Answer (score 3):

I didn't catch a space in the font name. It must be escaped:

```
set guifont=FixedsysTTF\ Monospace:h13
```

Comment: still no effect